# editor template align two components

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, alignment, kendo-grid, telerik-grid

I have an editor template for a grid using Telerik MVC grid and I have two kendo ui components in a grid cell. How can I get them to align next to each other i.e. side by side.

I have tried some css and placing them in div and align float but they render in separate spans and unsure on how to get them side by side any ideas?

Currently the search button is underneath the autocomplete textbox.

```
@model object

@*@Html.Kendo().AutoComplete().Name("LocationSearch").Placeholder("Type in your search item . . ").Filter("startswith").BindTo(new string[] { "UK","USA","FR","ES","TR","RU","PT"}).Separator(",")*@

@(Html.Kendo().AutoComplete()
.Name("DepartmentSearch")
.Filter("startswith")
.Placeholder("Type in your search item")
    .DataSource(source =>
    {
        source.Read(read =>
        {
            read.Action("GetDepartments", "Home");

        })
        .ServerFiltering(false);

    })

)

@(Html.Kendo().Button()
    .Name("Search")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { type = "button", style="min-width:20px !important;"})
    .Content("...")
    )
```

Comment: The autocomplete widget is created in a span added inline width via jquery and this worked.     <span tabindex="-1" role="presentation" class="k-widget k-autocomplete k-header k-state-default" style="width:65%;">          $("#DepartmentSearch").first().css('width', '65%');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The autocomplete widget is created in a span added inline width via jquery and this worked.               $("#DepartmentSearch").first().css('width', '65%');